# How would I create a button that runs a query in this table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-table

I'm creating a simple website for school where I list rows from a query in a html table.
The rows are created like this:

```
diGrupp.InnerHtml += "<tr><td>" + dRow.Field<int>("gruppeId").ToString() + "</td><td>" + dRow.Field<string>("gruppeNavn") + "</td><td>" + dRow.Field<DateTime>("opprettet").ToString() + "</td><td></td></tr>";
```

In the last column I want to add a button that runs a query with the "gruppeId" from the dRow (DataRow).

How would i do this in C#?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For starters, rather than creating all of the HTML as a string, use a `GridView`.

Comment: If you want to stick with a plain HTML table, you should consider building it with a [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the GridView to show the data in tabular format. This will also help you to bind the data with few lines of code.

```
DataTable dt = GetDataFromDataBase(); // Your data to bind with grid.

grdView.DataSource = dt;
grdView.DataBind();
```

You can also use the  `<asp:TemplateField>` of gridview to add the custom columns

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdView">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="First Column" DataField="DataColumnName1" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Second Column" DataField="DataColumnName2" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnCustomButton" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("MyKeyColumn") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Thank you, worked great.
Tried to do this at first, but didn't know about the TemplateField.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this functionality from html as below

```
test.InnerHtml = "<table><tr><td>" + dRow.Field<int>("gruppeId").ToString() + "</td>" +
                                 "<td>" + dRow.Field<string>("gruppeNavn") + "</td>" +
                                 "<td>" + dRow.Field<DateTime>("opprettet").ToString() + "</td> " +
                                 "<td><input type=button id='btn' value='click me' onclick='alert(" + dRow.Field<int>("gruppeId").ToString() + ");var p=this.parentNode.parentNode;p.parentNode.removeChild(p);' /></td></tr></table>";
```

in this code you will remove the datarow and also you can access groupid in this javascript function